# Phonegap 3.4 on Android 4.4 with pre-populated SQLite database

Tags: android, cordova

I have hybrid Android/phonegap application with phonegap version 2.5 that uses pre-populated SQLite database. On application installation database is copied from assets folder to "/data/data///app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db" location. Database is not working on Android 4.4. 
I am trying to  upgrade phonegap 3.4, but, while the app is compiles, it still has the same issue. Do I need to use Cordova-SQL Plugin (https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)? Does it work with pre-populated database and if it does - where database is stored? Also I found another plug-in -https://github.com/RikshaDriver/Cordova-PrePopulated-SQLitePlugin - but it said that it has issues with Android 4.4. 
Thank you for help,
Olga

Answer (score 0):

In 4.4+ You should replace the path "`/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db`" with "`/app_webview/databases/file__0/1`". In my app, it works on Android on 4.4.2